# When i use navbar dropdown in bootstrap, i can't have more than one click event in angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header component.In the header component i have child component called
app-notification-message. There is showerd bootstrap navbar dropdown so on click it will toggle the
dropup with the list element. The problem is when i click on the div with class wrapper -
markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler get executed but only once. After that there is not click event.Why is this hapening and how can i solve this ?

```
//header compo
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light dropup" *ngIf="userService.user">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <div class="header-logo header-logo--img">
    <img src="assets/img/ht-logo.svg" srcset="assets/img/ht-logo.svg" alt="Hedge Trade Sports Logo">
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-placement="top"
    data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav-custom">
      <ng-container *ngIf="isTheUserAuthenticated; else elseif1">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Welcome {{ userService.user.alias }} ({{ userService.user.balance | currency }})</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" (click)="logoutHandler()">
          <a class="nav-link main-nav__list-logout-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
            routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a>
        </li>
        
        
        <app-notification-message></app-notification-message>

      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
//app-notification-message component
<div class="wrapper" (click)="markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler()">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <svg role="img" class="dropdown-image">
      <image width="24" height="24" xlink:href="assets/img/notification.svg" />
    </svg>
    <div class="notification-icon">
      <span class="" [ngClass]= "(userService.user.unseen_notifications_no != 0) ? 'notification-icon__number-positive' : 'notification-icon__number-negative'">{{ userService.user.unseen_notifications_no }}</span>
    </div>
    <span class="up-icon">&#8963;</span>
  </a>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the (click)="markAllMessagesAsSeenHandler()" on the anchor tag with
nav-link dropdown-toggle classes.Then it worked.